# Salt grinder and corrosion

Tags: materials, metals, plastic, material-science, corrosion

I am looking for a kitchen salt grinder.

I know salt is an aggressive compound and it needs a little bit of attention when we design products.

Since most of grinders have plastic-made or stainless steel-made parts (I'm talking about grinder mechanism), and corrosion is virtually unavoidable,

As engineer, I have one (**+bonus**) question:

*I know salt can corrode metals, is it true for plastics too?*

**Bonus**. Concerning about health, is preferable to have metal corrosion (**rust**) or plastic corrosion?

Comment: Salt grinder for the table or for delivering salt onto roads from the back of a lorry aka grams per minute or kg per minute?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, plastics can't corrode. At all. It's a thing that metals do, and only metals.

Comment: @SolarMike I am taking about kitchen grider; add in OP

Comment: Neither plastic nor non-cheap-grade stainless steels should have issues with salt.

Comment: as fred_dot_u points out below, moisture is part of the story. In a kitchen device (unlike highway equipment) the salt will actually absorb moisture very nicely and keep all the inside surfaces of your mechanism dry. Now if you were to put it in the sink to soak before washing and leave it for a while... Different stainless alloys are noticably different in their sensitivity to salt and acid (remember, kitchen) corrosion. Don't know offhand, you can look it up. A grinder would in principle need something on the harder side, which limits the choices.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that salt is not necessarily corrosive if kept dry. Moisture will interact with the salt if there is sufficient humidity.

For your grinder objective, consider a coffee grinder using a burr mill. I've recently purchased a Mr. Coffee bean grinder that specifically notes that it's a burr mill design.

I can grind with this burr mill ordinary table salt to a level that approximates 20% of the original particle size. My objective is based on a future attempt to perform annealing of 3D printed objects, a project discovered on the internet.

I've only ground a few tens of grams of table salt, enough to examine for fineness but do not expect the plastic parts to be affected by the salt.

I don't expect the steel burr portion to be affected either, as it is kept indoors in a managed environment via air conditioning, approximately 50% humidity, non-condensing.